# UITableView is under the TabBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have a custom `UITableView` with custom cells (70px height for each cell).

I have also a 49px `UITabBar`, but it's hides the tableView.

I've tried to add this line to the TableView `awakeFromNib` method but it didn't work:

```
self.commentsTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 49, 0)
```

Any idea how can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using storyboard?

Comment: @VishalSonawane No, I'm using NIB/XIB file

Comment: You are using autolayout or auto sizing?

Comment: @VishalSonawane Yes, of course i use constraints

Comment: @BhadreshMulsaniya I didn't change anything about that, so I guess I'm using autolayout because it's the default option

Comment: Then why don't you give vertical space constraint between tabbar and your tableView?

Comment: what is the height of your table?

Comment: Are you really sure you don't use a storyboard in your project? I had a similar issue and was not related to UITableView, but to parent view controller that was managed in storyboard file. Let me know, so I can elaborate an answer if it's worth.

Answer (score 6):

i don't know what you did exactly, but try like this:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeAll;
self.tableview.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, CGRectGetHeight(self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame), 0.0f);
```

I hope, this will work.

Comment: You saved my day bro. Thank you so much. This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

This did the trick for me in Swift 3.

```
if let tabBarController = tabBarController {
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, tabBarController.tabBar.frame.height, 0.0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue when dealing with a table view in a navigation controller that did not have translucent bars. I performed a setup similar to the following:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Without this there is some extra fast inertia when slowly
    // scrolling to the top.
    extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true

    // Don't extend the tableview past the bottom bar, though.
    // If we do then a tab bar or bottom nav bar will block
    // content.
    edgesForExtendedLayout = [.top, .left, .right]
}
```

However, I later discovered that a couple of checkboxes were unchecked in a storyboard higher up the hierarchy. Specifically these two:

[image: Adjust scroll view insets]

[image: Under opaque bars]

Checking these two boxes removed the need to care about the content insets and the layout extending behavior in that view controller

Answer (score 1):

You should config the corresponding view controller with following code to remove the edges extend (It defaults to UIRectEdgeAll)

```
edgesForExtendedLayout = []
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
self.commentsTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(49, 0, 0, 0)
self.commentsTableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: -49), animated: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you changed `self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed=true` in previous view controller, then make sure to change it to `self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed=false` inside `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {}`

Answer (score -1):

Try to use constraints for tableView and TabBar like:

[image]