# Last cell on UITableView cut off. Solved adding one point as contentInset: iOS bug?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` where the last cell is cut off behind the `UITabBarController`. I set the bottom constraint of the tableView to the top of my bottomLayoutGuide. I also tried [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40461597/4473187) without success.

[image]

The only solution that worked was adding insets to the content (one point was enough):

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 1, right: 0)
```

Therefore I wonder if that's a normal behaviour or a scroll view bug.

Comment: set tableview bottom constraint to Top constraint of tabbar

Comment: That's the top of the bottomLayoutGuide

Comment: Can you just show me your constraint in storyboard?

Comment: I use SnapKit:
```tableView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.left.right.equalToSuperview()
            make.bottom.equalTo(bottomLayoutGuide.snp.top)
 }
```

Comment: Did you check the constraint at runtime? Maybe SnapKit doesn't create it right.